# Appsmith server is not starting because of MongoDB exception

Tags: mongodb, appsmith

My Appsmith instance just upgraded to `v1.6.4` and it's not booting up anymore. In the logs, I can see the exception below:

```
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 17 (ProtocolError): 'Attempt to switch database target during SASL authentication.' on server mongo:27017. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "Attempt to switch database target during SASL authentication.", "code": 17, "codeName": "ProtocolError"}
```

Is there anything I can do to bring up my Appsmith instance?

Answer (score 5):

This is a breaking change that was introduced in `v1.6.4` of Appsmith because of Spring library upgrades. A complete fix is described at: https://docs.appsmith.com/troubleshooting-guide/deployment-errors#server-not-booting-because-of-mongocommandexception

##### Step 1: Edit MongoDB URI

Adding `&authSource=admin` to the end of your `APPSMITH_MONGODB_URI` variable’s value in your `docker.env` file. For example, in your `docker.env` file, if you have the following line:

```sh
# Old config
APPSMITH_MONGODB_URI=mongodb://<your_username>:<your_password>@mongo/appsmith?retryWrites=true
```

Change it to the following (notice the only change is `&authSource=admin`. Do NOT copy-paste this whole line. Only add the `&authSource=admin` part to your existing value.

```sh
# New config
APPSMITH_MONGODB_URI=mongodb://<your_username>:<your_password>@mongo/appsmith?retryWrites=true&authSource=admin
```

Save the file.

##### Step 2: Restart server

Now restart your container with the following command:

```sh
sudo docker-compose up -d --force-recreate appsmith-internal-server
```

In a minute or two, the server should now come up and be ready.